# Cannot access from compute engine to on-premises machine over Google VPN Connection

Tags: vpn, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

It may be a trivial task but I could not manage and do not know how to debug. I have created a VPN Gateway and related tunnel to on-premises network. Route-based Tunnel is currently in **established** state.

Route is defined to for *default* network and directing ip range,  `10.25.0.0/24` to the VPN Tunnel.

My compute engine instance network interface is defined to use *default* network. In the *Network interface details* page, *route analysis* tab I can see the route for vpn connection is active and is not overriden by any other route.

When I try to ping a machine in the network, say `10.25.0.100` I got nothing. Traceroute also reports timeout. Eventually no traffic is received in the target network.

What am I missing? How can I inspect the problem, do you have any advice?

Comment: You could start by checking the firewall.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by confirming that this communication is allowed in your on-prem network. As per [GCP documentation on "On-premises rules"](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/how-to/configuring-firewall-rules#on-premises_rules) the recommendations are:

1) Configure rules to allow egress and ingress traffic to and from the IP ranges used by the subnets in your GCP network.

2) Permit all protocols and ports, or you may restrict traffic to only the necessary set of protocols and ports to meet your needs.

3) Allow ICMP traffic if you need to be able to communicate among on-premises systems and instances or resources in GCP using ping.

4) On-premise firewall rules can be implemented by both your network devices (for example, security appliances, firewall devices, switches, routers, and gateways) and in software running on your systems (such as firewall software included with an operating system). All firewalls “in the way” to GCP must be configured appropriately to allow traffic.

With traceroute from GCP end, you will not get usable information instead I would try it from on-prem end to make sure traffic destined to GCP going through the on-prem end of VPN tunnel.

I would also recommend you to consult the ["Checking connectivity"](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/resources/troubleshooting#checking_connectivity) section of the [GCP VPN Troubleshooting document](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/resources/troubleshooting) which has some good suggestions relevant to your scenario.

Comment: Dear Nur thank you for the response. Several times I have created vpn tunnels with the same configuration, in one incidence I have managed to connect to target network. But in order to replicate the issue I have deleted the tunnel and created again. It did not connect again! Then I tried to create it by gcloud cli in order to be sure I am using the same settings, I could not create "route-based" tunnel by gcloud, It always creates "policy-based" and it does not convert to route-based even if I create route afterwards. Do you have any advice?

Comment: You can follow this GCP documentation on ["Creating a Route Based VPN"](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/how-to/creating-route-based-vpns) which has all the gcloud command to ["create gateway and tunnel for route based VPN"](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/how-to/creating-route-based-vpns#creating-gw-tunnel). I would also recommend to delete the tunnel configuration in both ends (on-prem end and GCP end) and start fresh.

Comment: I have created another question regarding creating route based vpn, you may find the detailed info here: https://serverfault.com/questions/930593/gcloud-cannot-create-route-based-vpn